# Reading/Displaying the actual byte (C++)

Tags: c++, binary, hex, iostream, cout

```
int main()
{
    cout << hex;
    cout << (0xe & 0x3); // 1110 & 0011 -> 0010 (AND)
    cout << endl;
    cout << (0xe | 0x3); // 1110 | 0011 -> 1111 (OR)
    cout << endl;
    cout << (0xe ^ 0x3); // 1110 ^ 0011 -> 1101 (XOR)
    return 0;
}
```

When using cout, it displays the translation (2, f, and d) vs the actual value (0010, 1111, and 1101). How do I make it so that it display this vs what the bit goes with?

Answer (score 3):

These are the correct values for the `hex` representation of the binary values that you have requested: `0010` is 2, `1111` is f, and `1101` is d.

If you would like to print a binary representation, you can borrow `convBase` function from [here](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html), or build your own.

```
cout << convBase((0xe & 0x3), 2); // 1110 & 0011 -> 0010 (AND)
cout << endl;
cout << convBase((0xe | 0x3), 2); // 1110 | 0011 -> 1111 (OR)
cout << endl;
cout << convBase((0xe ^ 0x3), 2); // 1110 ^ 0011 -> 1101 (XOR)
```

Comment: How would I include the few 0's before the first 1? eg: 0010 instead of 10 for the first line.

Comment: @sfxworks You can use a combination of `setfill` and `setw` in `<iomanip>`, take a look at an example: [link](http://ideone.com/Hijrw).

Answer (score 1):

***For example:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string convBase(unsigned long v, long base) {
  if (base < 2 || base > 16) return "Error: base out of range;";

  string result;
  string digits = "0123456789abcdef";

  do {
    result = digits[v % base] + result;
    v /= base;
  } while (v);

  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int a = 0xe;
  int b = 0x3;

  cout << hex;

  cout << (a & b) << " - " << convBase(a & b, 2);
  cout << endl;
  cout << (a | b) << " - " << convBase(a | b, 2);
  cout << endl;
  cout << (a ^ b) << " - " << convBase(a ^ b, 2);
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

***Output:***

2 - 10
f - 1111
d - 1101

Comment: Maybe `convBase(0, base)` should be `"0"` instead of `""`